# How to force Hibernate to add quotes to generated SQL statements?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, syntax-error

Hibernate is generating invalid SQL for a particular criteria query. I can manually fix the query by adding single quotes to the value being used in the WHERE clause.

To fix it, I changed the query from:

```
where (role0_.ROLE_ID=2L )
```

to:

```
where (role0_.ROLE_ID=`2L` )
```

How to force hibernate to add single quotes (in mysql it is single quotes but in other database systems it might be something else) to enclose the **values** used in generated SQL queries?

The full generated query is:

```
select permission1_.PERMISSION_ID as PERMISSION1_12_,
    permission1_.IS_REQUIRED as IS2_12_,
    permission1_.SOURCE_ROLE_ID as SOURCE3_12_,
    permission1_.TARGET_ROLE_ID as TARGET4_12_
from (
        select ROLE_ID,
        NAME,
        DESCRIPTION,
        IS_ACTION,
        LABEL,
        null as FIRST_NAME,
        null as LAST_NAME,
        null as PASSWORD_HASH,
        1 as clazz_ from GROUPS
    union
        select ROLE_ID,
            NAME,
            null as DESCRIPTION,
            null as IS_ACTION,
            null as LABEL,
            FIRST_NAME,
            LAST_NAME,
            PASSWORD_HASH,
            2 as clazz_ from USERS
    )
role0_ inner join PERMISSIONS permission1_ on role0_.ROLE_ID=permission1_.SOURCE_ROLE_ID
    where (role0_.ROLE_ID=2L )
```

Basically I'd like this single quotes to be added by Hibernate.

The criteria query that generated this query is:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();

Class<?> queryScopeClass = temp.pack.commons.user.Role.class;
Root<?> from = criteriaQuery.from(queryScopeClass);

Path<?> idAttrPath = from.get("id");
// also tried criteriaBuilder.equal(idAttrPath, new Long(2))
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(idAttrPath, criteriaBuilder.literal(new Long(2)))
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

Path<?> attributePath = from.get("permissions");
PluralAttributePath<?> pluralAttrPath = (PluralAttributePath<?>)attributePath;
PluralAttribute<?, ?, ?> pluralAttr = pluralAttrPath.getAttribute();

Join<?, ?> join = from.join((SetAttribute<Object,?>)pluralAttr);

TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery.select(join));
return (List<P>)typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Please let me know if you have any clues on how to force Hibernate to add those single quotes to the values (not the column/table name).

In my entity Role, the id property that appears in the WHERE clause is of long type, of course.

**Follow up:** The type of the id column in the database is bingint:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ROLE_ID       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

...
```

This is how the Role class has been annotated:

```
@Entity(name="Role")
@Table(name = "ROLES")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@javax.persistence.TableGenerator(
    name="GENERATED_IDS",
    table="GENERATED_IDS",
    valueColumnName = "ID"
)
public abstract class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * The id of this role. Internal use only.
     * 
     * @since 1.0
     */
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="GENERATED_IDS")
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    protected long id;


    /**
     * Set of permissions granted to this role.
     * 
     * @since 1.0
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy="sourceRole")
    protected Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();

...

}
```

I use table per class inheritance strategy, that's why you see the union in the generated query for User and Group entities. They extend Role. Id is defined in Role.

Thank you!

Eduardo

Comment: I don't think ticks or quotations are your problem here.  Why are you using bigint(20) to store the id?  Can you post your mapping or annotated entity?

Comment: @hisdrewness: sure, I have added the annotated class section to the post. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Looks like you can just change your id to the `Long` class instead of a primitive.  Hibernate will then simply generate the query to be ROLE_ID=2, which is 100% valid since numbers don't require ticks or quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your id to the `Long` class type instead of a primitive. Hibernate will then simply generate the query to be ROLE_ID=2, which is 100% valid since numbers don't require ticks or quotes.

Comment: @Eduardo: Glad you solved it. I like you to read this answer too, its related somewhat.

Answer (score 7):

The hibernate property *hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true* will do the trick